Missing headers in fetch and XMLHttpRequest
When doing a CORS request using either fetch or XMLHttpRequest, some headers are missing from the response.
To be precise, those APIs drop all headers, that are not explicitely "whitelisted" by the server for cross-origin requests (using Access-Control-Expose-Headers). That I know.
However, if those headers should only be visible when the request is not cross-origin, why does the server send those headers anyway?
What I mean is, most headers are not visible to fetch and xhr, but they are visible to the browser - as evident when having a look at the network tab. It clearly shows all the headers I'd expect in the response, even those not available via the programmatic calls.
Since the headers exist and are sent by the server, couldn't there be a way to still read those headers programmatically? Why is there this restriction between what the browser sees and what it hands to the APIs?

The Access-Control-Allow-Headers is about headers to be allowed in requests.

@Pointy ah yes, I meant ...Expose...

"Why is there this restriction between what the browser sees and what it hands to the APIs?" Security reasons. That's the whole point of CORS.

@gre_gor CORS is configured server-side. Which makes sense, if the client is in control, you can't expect security. But with these headers, if they actually DO reach the client (browser), nothing you as a backend dev could do would stop the browser from handing the headers to the script. You have to trust the browser to protect your backend or headers or whatever, which can't be right...

"However, if those headers should only be visible when the request is not cross-origin, why does the server send those headers anyway?" Because this is only relevant for browsers and CORS. The server doesn't know if I use cUrl, Postman or Firefox. The server also doesn't know if it's a cross-origin request or not. "Since the headers exist and are sent by the server, couldn't there be a way to still read those headers programmatically?" If you find a way, it's a browser bug and has to be fixed.
